# Wirelessly sync music folder to microSD card

Tags: sync, external-sd, cloud

I am looking for a way to sync, wirelessly or over a cloud service, a (music) folder from my computer to the microSD card on my rooted phone.
I've been trying this on Android MM with Titanium Media Sync app but it seems MM restricts the app from writing on the SD-card "Error. Failed to create local folder." 
I recall to be able to do so on another phone with CynogenMod...

Comment: You could take a look at the *FolderSync* app (which is what I use). Cannot test it on MM, though, as I have no MM device.

Comment: ok, thanx! I'll have a look. which OS do you use?

Comment: I use Linux on all of my computers. But *FolderSync* supports all kind of protocols, including CIFS (in case you're using Windows; I use SFTP/SCP here with Linux).

Comment: cool, I also mainly use linux. and which Androd versions do you use? :)

Comment: Mostly 4.4 (though my tabbies are still stuck on 4.1/4.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the feature that TMS is missing is superuser permissiom request. *FolderSync* as noted in the comments does asks for superuser priviledges and can perform two way syncing!